Ngx-leaflet user imagem marker
I'm working on a project ngx-leaflet on angular where I need to display a list of users on a map.
Each user has an image and their latitude and longitude coordinates. I want to customize the markers on the map so that each user's marker shows their image as a round icon, similar to the markers on this website: https://palworld.gg/pt-BR/map. However, I've been struggling to achieve this. Do you have any solutions or suggestions on how to implement this?
